# How to correct mock two methods with similar name and different parameters?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have four methods with similar name and different parameters.

```
public MyResponse send(MyObject my);
public MyResponse send(MyObject my, long time);
public MyResponse send(List<MyObject> my);
public MyResponse send(List<MyObject> my, long time);
```

I need to mock two of them. When i tried to

```
when(mock.send(anyList())).thenReturn(any());
when(mock.send(any(MyObject.class))).thenReturn(any());
```

I have an exception
`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Invalid use of argument matchers! 1 matchers expected 2 recorded.` How can i fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] the post and show the class being mocked, in particular the signature of the two methods being mocked.

Comment: @Turing85 i did it

Comment: Those are not the full method definitions. The return types of the methods are missing. Please also add the full stack trace.

Comment: @Turing85 i thinks it is not necessary, but i updated the post

Comment: You should return an actual object coming from `thenReturn`. Not a matcher

Comment: To exapand on @NicoVanBelle comment: we would write something like: `final MyResponse toReturn = ...; when(mock.send(anyList())).thenReturn(toReturn);`

Comment: thenReturn(any()) seems like an invalid use of any(). any() is a matcher that matches any argument. thenReturn specifies which value the method should return when the match is successful.